# Visual Studio Code - Generating Barrel Files (Index.ts) Automatically

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I didn't really understand barrel files when I started out on my first Typescript Project.  I do now, because my imports have become unwieldy and difficult to manage as my solution has grown.

I'm presently going through every section of my solution manually typing out the exports for the index.ts files in each folder.

Is there a way to automate this?  I reckon it will take me a day to do it manually  I have searched for a plugin but with no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two useful extensions for auto barrelling:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikerhyssmith.ts-barrelr
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikehanson.auto-barrel

Answer (score 0):

I ran across an extension to VS Code that provides functionality for creating barrels either at the directory level or project level.  You can search for NG-42 at Visual Studio Market place.  Here is the link to the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NG-42.ng-fortytwo-vscode-extension).  Note the disclaimer that it is actively being developed at time of this post so use at your own risk.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Updated answer to include more context.  Was being lazy and just trying to quickly help before.